# Critical points in a function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Consider the function $f(x)=(a^2 -3a+2)\cos(x/2) + (a-1)x$. We have to find set of values of $a$ for which $f(x)$ possess critical points.
When we put $a=1$, we get both $f(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) =0$. So we can say $f(x)$ possess critical points for $a=1$. But in the answer, $a=1$ is not included. Why?

Comment: You said it yourself: If $a=1$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Not a very interesting function ... Technically, indeed also $f'(x) = 0$ but I would not say that a constant function has any critical points.

Comment: You can play around with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nkyzggmvbc

Comment: What is the definition of a `critical point` that your textbook uses?

Comment: Critical points of a function are points where either f'(x)=0 or f'(x) doesn't exist

Comment: @Lakshay Then you are correct in that $\,f\,$ has critical points for $\,a=1\,$, in fact the entire domain.

Comment: Should i then correct the answer

Comment: @Lakshay If *you* wrote it ;-) else you may want to point out  the omission to whoever did.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Compute $f'(x)$ and distinguish three cases: $a=1,a=2$ and $ 1 \ne a \ne 2$
2. Compute all $x$ with $f'(x)=0$